# Why can't I call collect_into on a par_iter?

Tags: rust

I want to minimize the amount of allocations my program does, so instead of calling `.collect()` on a rayon par_iter, I try using `collect_into()`, collecting into an existing Vec.

Here is some sample code:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use rayon::iter::IndexedParallelIterator;

fn main() {
    let a:Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3,4];
    let mut b: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(100);
    a.into_par_iter().map(|x|x*2).collect_into(&mut b);
    println!("{:?}",a);
}
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7139f0fa232bc3fa781155d4f58e189d)

Instead of building, the compiler prints

```
error[E0599]: no method named `collect_into` found for type `rayon::iter::map::Map<rayon::vec::IntoIter<u8>, [closure@src/main.rs:8:27: 8:33]>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:35
   |
 8 |     a.into_par_iter().map(|x|x*2).collect_into(&mut b);
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In your example, it's not obvious what you mean by " minimize the amount of allocations" because you don't save anything here

Comment: by the way, `collect_into` doesn't exist in the crate you maybe probably want `collect_into_vec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method has been renamed to `collect_into_vec()` in the 1.0 release of Rayon, which you appear to be using.